# Is there any problem to reuse the prime p, g and a in Diffie-Hellman?

Tags: key-exchange, diffie-hellman

Suppose I always reuse p, g and a in DH and there is someone monitoring my communication. Is there a way this person can use this to perform some kind of attack to me?

I believe that reusing p and g isn't a big issue, however I'm not quite sure about a.

Comment: You might get good answers on Cryptography.SE.

Comment: @poncho: Gack! I don't know what I was thinking. Plus it didn't really add anything given the answers, so -- deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the seminal paper of [Diffie-Hellman](https://www-ee.stanford.edu/%7Ehellman/publications/24.pdf) describes Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange<sup>*</sup> (DHKE), we have Alice and Bob want to key exchange and Oscar is the bad guy (Oscar is not mentioned in the paper). In DHKE settings

- $p$ is a public prime modulus known by Alice and Bob and Oscar.
- $g$ is a public base known by Alice and Bob and Oscar and need not to be a prime number.

The $a$ and $b$ are random values ( not necessarily a prime) generated by Alice and Bob per session. After the key is generated they can delete $a$ and $b$. They are not transferred as $a$ or $b$, they are transferred as $g^a$ and $g^b$.

> -This is called ***ephemeral-ephemeral DHKE*** (or standard DHKE)

Standard DHKE and vulnerable to Man-in-the-Middle-Attack ( an active attacker who replaces both public keys with his own and creates two channels). To mitigate you need authentication as in TLS.

ephemeral-ephemeral DHKE has [forward secrecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy) that generates a new key per session and discards at the end of the session. There is no easy way for an attacker to find the exchanged keys if they are erased.

As a **passive** man in the middle, Oscar sees $g^a$, $g^b$ and wants to calculate $g^{ab}$. This is called [Diffie–Hellman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_problem) and for some groups, this is a hard problem.

To access $a$ or $b$, Oscar must solve the [Discrete Logarithm Problem (DLP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) and [generic algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm#Algorithms) for DLP runs in $O(\sqrt{p})$. To protect against the generic discrete logarithm attacks the $p$ is chosen a safe prime $p = 2q+1$ where $q$ is another prime aginst [Pohlig-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm). For the key sizes see [keylength.com](https://www.keylength.com/en/compare/).

> - There is also ***static-ephemeral DHKE***  where one side always chooses a new random $a$ and one is fixed $b$.
> - There is also ***static-static DHKE***  where both sides use fixed $a$ and $b$.

### So your case:

It is either static-static or static-ephemeral.

**In short:** No problem for $p$ and $g$. But the Oscar doesn't get $a$ and $b$ as a passive man in the middle. If you use again, he will see the same values $g^a$ and $g^b$, however, you will not have forward secrecy.

---

**Note:** ***static DHKE's***  are [removed from TLS 1.3](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/67604/18298).

<sup>* Actually, in DHKE, the key is established not exchanged.</sup>

Comment: So, if I always use the same 'a' everytime, I wouldn't have to worry about anyone trying to attack me. Even if Oscar could know that I'm reusing 'a', because g^a is the same. Is it correct?

Comment: It all depend on chosen ```p```, if p is small(768 bit or less) , oscar can break it and retrieve ```a```. Typically p is chosen as safe prime i.e. ```p = 2q+1```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there is one potential problem to reusing $a$ values:

Background: $g$ generates a subgroup of size $q$; $q$ is a divisor of $p-1$, but it is usually selected as a prime, and is hence less than $p-1$ (which is obviously composite).

What an attacker could do is, for any small prime $r$ which divides $(p-1)/q$, he can potentially learn $a \bmod q$; he does this by negotiating with you, selecting as his share a value $g^b \cdot h$, where $b$ is a value he knows (doesn't matter what it is), and $h$ is a value of order $q$.  Then, when you'll do is generate a shared secret $(g^b \cdot h)^a = g^{ab} \cdot h^{a \bmod r}$; he can easily compute $g^{ab}$, and so he knows the shared secret is one of $r$ different values (depending on the value of $a \bmod r$).

If $(p-1)/q$ has a number of small primes, the attacker can deduce quite a bit about $a$.  One example of such a $p, q$ pair which has been actually proposed is Group 23 of [RFC 5114](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5114); this particular group has $$(p-1)/q = 2 * 3 * 3 * 5 * 43 * 73 * 157 * 387493 * 605921 * 5213881177 * 352891
0760717 * 83501807020473429349 * C489$$ (where $C489$ is a 489 digit composite), and so the attacker can actually deduce enough to make brute force search of a 256 bit exponent feasible.

Now, there are several ways to protect yourself from this:

- When you receive a value $b$, always check to see if $b^q = 1$; if not, someone is playing games.  This works, but it is expensive.
- Use a 'safe prime' group; that is, one where $p-1 = 2q$.  This implies that the attacker can learn one bit of $a$ (the least significant bit), but nothing else.
- Don't reuse $a$ values; what the attacker learns is the value $a \bmod r$ for the $a$ you used with the exchange with him; if you use different values of $a$ for unrelated exchanges, this doesn't buy him anything.

Also, note that the idea of using $q = p-1$ really isn't a protection; if $q$ has a small factor $r$, the attacker can also learn $a \bmod r$ just by examining $g^a$, hence the same vulnerability is there (except that not reusing $a$ doesn't actually provide protection).